# How to do select between an IN .. Read more

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to do a mysql select where i need to get all the rows where the column is equal to values from 1100 - 1400.
The problem is that i am getting values though a IN too.

My code:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM places WHERE number IN (3500, 2950, 2942, && 1100-1400 )";
```

But it doesnt give me all the results from 1100 to 1400.

I hope some1 can help me.

Best Regards,

Tyler Brand

Comment: `SELECT * FROM places WHERE number IN (3500, 2950, 2942) OR (number >= 1100 AND number <= 1400)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can separate the two conditions (with `OR`):

```sql
WHERE number IN (3500, 2950, 2942)
   OR number BETWEEN 1100 AND 1400
```